# Web Role Deployment Error

Tags: azure, tfs, azure-web-roles, tfs-2015, ms-release-management

Using TFS 2015 Update 3 - Release Manager.  I have the exact same setup for QA and Live, both work just fine.  I tried creating a new build off the same Source Version, same error.  I was able to upload the cscfg and cspkg via the Azure Portal without issue.  Any ideas?

```
2016-10-18T21:53:06.3839794Z Get-AzureDeployment -ServiceName BeethovenUAT -Slot Staging -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable azureDeploymentError
2016-10-18T21:53:08.6183599Z Set-AzureDeployment -Upgrade -ServiceName BeethovenUAT -Package \\storage\tfs builds\8517\UAT\BeethovenMicrosoftAzureCloudService.cspkg -Configuration \\storage\tfs builds\8517\UAT\BeethovenMicrosoftAzureCloudService.cspkg -Slot Staging -Label 8517 10/18/2016 22:53:06 -ExtensionConfiguration <extensions>
2016-10-18T21:56:37.1813672Z ##[error]Request Entity Too Large
```

Comment: There are many questions (and answers) regarding the error "Request Entity Too Large" tagged with [tag:azure]. You may want to do a bit of searching on those questions, since this is likely a duplicate of one of them.

Comment: I spent several hours searching last night.  The 'Request Entity Too Large' error tends to be with WCF calls and for what they are, it makes sense.  The issue I have is this is being returned via PowerShell in Release Manager which is connecting to the Azure API, and I have no access or control over it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So someone finally noticed my issue and it blows my mind that no one, including me, saw this.

2016-10-18T21:53:08.6183599Z Set-AzureDeployment -Upgrade -ServiceName BeethovenUAT -Package \storage\tfs builds\8517\UAT\BeethovenMicrosoftAzureCloudService.cspkg **-Configuration \storage\tfs builds\8517\UAT\BeethovenMicrosoftAzureCloudService.cspkg** -Slot Staging -Label 8517 10/18/2016 22:53:06 -ExtensionConfiguration

Should actually be

2016-10-18T21:53:08.6183599Z Set-AzureDeployment -Upgrade -ServiceName BeethovenUAT -Package \storage\tfs builds\8517\UAT\BeethovenMicrosoftAzureCloudService.cspkg **-Configuration \storage\tfs builds\8517\UAT\BeethovenMicrosoftAzureCloudService.cscfg** -Slot Staging -Label 8517 10/18/2016 22:53:06 -ExtensionConfiguration

Comment: What's the difference between them, they are still the same between two versions. Am I missing something？

Comment: I originally had the cspkg set for both the Package and Configuration Arguments.